# how do i iterate the pair array arguments passed as a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, parameter-passing, std-pair

how do i iterate the pair array arguments passed as a pointer ?

i had tried to use as reference pair &arr . but it doesnt worked either . can i pass `pair<lli,lli> a[n];` as reference ??

```
#pragma GCC optimize ("O3")
#pragma GCC target ("sse4")
#define LOCAL
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define ff first
#define ss second
typedef long long int lli;
typedef unsigned long long int ulli;

void yeah( pair<lli,lli> *arr ){
    // cout << arr[0].ff;  100
    //this doesnt work :(
    for(auto e : arr){
        cout << e.ff << " " << e.ss << endl;
    }
}


int main() {
    int n = 10;
    pair<lli,lli> a[n];
    a[0].ff = 100;
    a[1].ss = 150;

    yeah(a);
}
```

this is the error im getting

> prog.cpp: In function 'void yeah(std::pair*)':
>   prog.cpp:13:18: error: no matching function for call to 'begin(std::pair*&)'
>        for(auto e : arr){
>                    ^
>                     ^

Comment: maybe use std::vector? or array?

Comment: why cant i use this only sir

Comment: `arr` tells `for` where to start, but how would `for` know where to stop?

Comment: thanks for teaching i know something now

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: im doing competitive programming so it doesnt matter @Evg

Comment: @tusse IMO, it does matter. Competitive programming should not be a synonym for sloppy programming. Don't pick bad habits from the very beginning.

Comment: unfortunately common practices in competitive programming are opposing common practices elsewhere, eg `#define ff first` and the typedefs should be a no-go when you ask others to read your code, because they may save some keystrokes for you but obfuscate the code for anybody else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend ditching the VLA (which is not part of C++ anyway) and use `std::vector` instead. Include `<vector>` and change the declaration to this:

```
std::vector<std::pair<lli, lli>> a(n);
```

And the function's signature to:

```
void yeah(std::vector<std::pair<lli, lli>> &arr)
```

Comment: Pass `std::vector` by (`const`) reference.

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution with fixed-size arrays:

```
template<std::size_t size>
void foo(std::pair<int, int> (&arr)[size]) {
    for (auto e : arr) {
        ...
    }
}

constexpr std::size_t n = 10;   // should be known at compile time
std::pair<int, int> a[n];

foo(a);
```